# neo4j lucene score is always 0.0

Tags: java, lucene, neo4j

We are trying to find the scores assigned by the lucene to the neo4j query results.

```
IndexManager index = graphDb.index();
Index<Node> fulltextMovies = index.forNodes("Restaurant");
QueryContext query = new QueryContext("name:" + term + "*");
TermQuery t = new TermQuery(new Term("name", term + "m*"));

IndexHits<Node> hits = fulltextMovies.query(t);
System.out.println(hits.currentScore());
```

The last line of the code always prints 0.0

Do we have to define the custom scores to get this working? As per my understanding, lucene assigns a score to every search result. If so,. I should see a lucene score against my query results. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `currentScore()` only while consuming the iterator from the index query. As an example:

```
try (IndexHits<Node> hits = index.query(t)) {
    for (Node node : hits) {
        System.out.println(node + " " + hits.currentScore());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. I'll try this solution and will update this thread. :-)

Comment: I tried the steps you mentioned, but the result is same. I'm getting the 0.0 score for all my search items now.